# Azure Functions - run code block before function execution

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have a series of Node based HTTP Azure Functions each of which needs to undertake some checks before the function can be executed. The checks are based on the contents of some HTTP headers.

I've implemented the checks in a helper and can add that to the head of each function e.g.

```
if (myHelper.doChecksPass()) {
  // Execute the main body of the function code
  context.res.status = 200;
}
else {
  context.res.status = 403;
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a slicker way to do this rather than duplicating the above code into each function? I'm thinking along the lines of something which runs on function execution and before the main function body which can stop the execution of the function and return the 403.

I've checked the MS docs and I can't see anything but I might just be missing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Andy! I do not know how complex your checks are, but would it be possible to route the traffic through API Management and do the checks in the inbound policy section? That way you would be able to have 1 "check" for all of your functions. This assumes that you would be fine with using API Management ofc :)

Comment: You can also check what CDN can offer - some of them allows to add rules that check i.e. headers for some values before passing it next.

Comment: Middleware is available in .NET, might be time to switch … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#benefits-of-isolated-worker-process

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Unfortunately API management is probably a no go on this one and a switch to .NET is out of the question due to client constraints. I'm traditionally a .NET developer so trying to find my way with node.